# File explorer bug in Windows server 2016

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2016

I am having a bug on Windows Server 2016 on File explorer. Basically, When I open file explorer with **start > file explorer** everything works file. But if I pin the file explorer on the Taskbar, when I click on it, it just blinks a nothing happens.

Can you please help to solve this ?

**Update**
I am having the same problem if I right click on **start** and select **file explorer**. Like the first case, nothing happens.